# conditional statements inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, render

I am trying to create a comment section for a site im working on. Once the comment form (inside `AfterCommentButtonClick`)  is submitted, the state `formSubmitted` changes from `false` to `true` which triggers a conditional statement inside the render method. This calls a child component which receives the users comment and does some styling with it. The issue im having is that, i want my app to allow more than one comment. Is there a way to save the previously rendered comment, and then create a new instance of `<UserComment>` as currently, following form submittal the old one is simply overwritten. I also need to reset the `textInput` state following the submittal of the form, to reset the form for the next comment. However, again im not sure how to do this without entering `setState` inside render, which will cause an infinite loop

```
import React from 'react'
import UserComment from './UserComment'

class CommentSection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {selectedFile: this.props.selectedFile, textinput : '', formSubmitted:false}


    }

    onFormSubmit (event){
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({formSubmitted:true})

    }


    render(){

        //conditional render depending on if comment button has been clicked or not. props.selectedFile only
        //passed here from parent if user clicks comment button
        const file = this.props.selectedFile
        let messageToUser
        if (file !=null){
             messageToUser = <AfterCommentButtonClick 
                                selectedFile = {file}
                                onTextChange = {(e)=> this.setState({textinput: e.target.value})}
                                onFormSubmit = {(e)=>this.onFormSubmit(e)}
                            />
         }else {
          messageToUser = <BeforeCommentButtonClick />  
          } 

          return (
            <div>
                <div> {messageToUser}</div>
                <div className="ui container comments">
                {this.state.formSubmitted && 
                    <UserComment commentText = {this.state.textinput}/>
                     /*conditionally send text typed into comment bar if user submits form*/    

                }

                </div>
            </div>
            )
    }       

}
```

Comment: you can keep the array of submitted comments inside the app's state. And in the render function, you can use `.map` to iterate over the array and render the `<UserComment>` for each array element (comment).

Comment: You need to completely separate all state logic from render. You have two separate things happening in an app / a component: a) user interaction changes state - - b) render() turns state into HTML. a) and b) do not mix, ever. For render, there's no "after" or "before". It has to deal with all possible app states, and should be written in a way that it can be called by React at any point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a functional component to render all of your  submitted comments. To do this, you would keep an array of 'submitted comments' in state and, on submission of a new comment, just add the new user comment to the array of submitted comments. Pass that submitted comments array from state to your new functional component. Use the `array.map()` function to render the array of submitted components by rendering a `<UserComment/>` for each item in the array.

So, on submission of a User Comment, it would just add to the submitted comments component, the UI re-renders and updates with the new UserComment in your submitted comments.  This should be entirely separate logic.

i.e. Render method of your `<CommentsSection/>` component would look something like this:

```
render() {
   return (<div>
      {this.props.submittedComments.map((comment) => (
         <UserComment author={comment.author} content={comment.content}></UserComment>))}
   </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another state field to store the comments in an array. So, when you get a new comment, you do this:

```
this.setState({
    comments: [...this.state.comments, newComment]
});
```

And in your render method, you map over that array and display a single comment component for every comment in this.state.comments

```
this.state.comments.map(comment => <UserComment commentText = {comment}}/>);
```